# Getting an ajax call from url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I have an ajax request that works fine when I just put the file name ex:

```
var security = function(){
    var link = $('#chosen').attr('href');
        $.get('func.php',function(result)         {
            if (result > 75 && result % 5 === 0){
                    $('#chosen').attr("href", link);


            }else{
             $('#chosen').attr('href','https://www.google.com');

            }
        });
        $("#chosen").click(function(){
            $.get('func2.php',function(results){
            if (results === results){
                location.reload();
            }
        });
        });
        $("#chosen").click(function(){
            $.get('func3.php',function(results){
            if (results === results){

            }
        });
        });
};
```

I wanna make the func.php functions recheable from anywhere so i havean url named cligit.com i tried linking it like thisbut when i do that it stops working

```
var security = function(){
    var link = $('#chosen').attr('href');
        $.get('http://www.vanillacomp.com/browse/func.php?callback=?func.php',function(result)         {
            if (result > 75 && result % 5 === 0){
                    $('#chosen').attr("href", link);


            }else{
             $('#chosen').attr('href','https://www.google.com');

            }
        });
        $("#chosen").click(function(){
            $.get('http://www.cligit.com/func2.php',function(results){
            if (results === results){
                location.reload();
            }
        });
        });
        $("#chosen").click(function(){
            $.get('http://www.cligit.com/func3.php',function(results){
            if (results === results){

            }
        });
        });
};
```

Comment: Look into **same origin policy** -- you will probably see an error about origin in your console.

Comment: Cannot make cross domain requests. Need to use some kind of padded ajax instead.

Comment: The easiest way to get AJAX data from a different domain is to use [JSON-P](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about), which you *almost* appear to be using already.

Comment: Don't use Google either for your else.  That doesntnbwork

Comment: @Blazemonger how can i use json-p ivenever used it before

Answer (score 0):

Add these to headers in your `func.php` page

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
```

Hope this helps,Thank you